# Java file compiles with having mismatching directory location and package declaration

Tags: java

I am facing an odd issue. Java source file is under `/home/gftrelv204/lib_build/sfw.24/src/log/Logger.java`, but in the file itself (`Logger.java`), the package declaration is `com.giftssoft.fts.log.
Strange thing is, that`Logger.java` file compiles successfully. I was expecting compiler to complain about the directory structure not matching the package declaration.

```
$ javac -encoding cp1252 ./src/log/Logger.java
$

$ head -1 ./src/log/Logger.java

package com.giftssoft.log;
```

Comment: `javac` works fine without the source file being in a particular directory structure based on its package. It's the `.class` file which should be in a particular place for the class to be loaded at runtime. If your project *runs* without errors, perhaps the class files are all being packaged into a `jar` file first? Please give more information.

Comment: You are right, yes it is getting compiled into a jar with appropriate package structure. Thanks